# Safe USB HDD eject from cli (raid on top)

Tags: linux, hard-drive, usb, backup, mdadm

I have 6 USB HDDs which i use to store a externel backup of my homeserver.
Over the HDDs is a Linux Software RAID5.

What is the correct way to "stop everything" and eject the HDDs safe so i can unplug them without shutdown the whole server?

After the backup process was complete, i have shutdown the server (so i do not destroy the raid with failed HDDs) and unplugged them.

I wonder if there is a other and more comfortable way to do this.
Is it just a simple `mdadm --stop /dev/md/<what-ever>`?

Comment: So the 6 external drives are all members of a RAID 5?

Comment: @JoepvanSteen Yes. That is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried it with `mdadm --stop` & `udisksctl` and it works like expected.

First unmount the volume, and then:

```sh
mdadm --stop /dev/mdX
udisksctl power-off -b /dev/sdX
```

Repeat the last command for each disk.
I let the question open, perhaps someone has something to say about my approach.

Comment: Does it work to only do `eject /dev/sdX` where X is the letter of the *RAID drive*?

Comment: I have tried it before, eject had no impact on my external drives. They where still spinning and not in standby/idle.